# Flyway change versioning in production system

Tags: flyway

I have started a project using a simple incremental versioning scheme like `V1__`, `V2__`, `V3__`.

I'm not happy with it. It causes problems when working on multiple branches: pull-requests need to be updated with the latest number when a different branch which has added migrations is merged before.

We have already deployed migrations to production.

Is it possible to change the versioning scheme after the fact?

I feel that simply renaming it will cause Flyway to throw an Exception. We cannot clear the production database.

Does anybody have experience with this? Any tips are appreciated.